# Case sensitive LINQ to DataSet

Tags: unit-testing, ado.net, case-sensitive, linq-to-dataset

I am having an issue with a strongly typed `DataSet` exhibiting case-sensitivity using [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) to retrieve and filter data.  In my example project, I have created a strongly typed DataSet called DataSet1.  It contains a single `DataTable` called Customers.  To instantiate and populate, I create a couple of rows (notice the casing on the names):

```
// Instantiate
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();

// Insert data
ds.Customers.AddCustomersRow(1, "Smith", "John");
ds.Customers.AddCustomersRow(2, "SMith", "Jane");
```

Next, I can easily fetch/filter using the DataSet's built-in `Select` functionality:

```
var res1 = ds.Customers.Select("LastName LIKE 'sm%'");
Console.WriteLine("DataSet Select: {0}", res1.Length);

DataSet Select: 2
```

The trouble begins when attempting to use LINQ to DataSet to perform the same operation:

```
var res2 = from c in ds.Customers where c.LastName.StartsWith("sm") select c;
Console.WriteLine("LINQ to DataSet: {0}", res2.Count());
LINQ to DataSet: 0
```

I've already checked the instantiated DataSet's `CaseSensitive` property as well as the Customer DataTable's `CaseSensitive` property--both are false.  I also realize that when using the `Select` methodology, the `DataSet` performs the filtering and the LINQ query is doing something else.

My hope and desire for this type of code was to use it to Unit Test our [Compiled LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335.aspx) queries so I can't really change all the current queries to use:

```
...where c.LastName.StartsWith("sm", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select c;
```

...as that changes the query in SQL.  Thanks all for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to DataSets still use normal managed functions, including the standard `String.StartsWith` method.
It is fundamentally impossible for these methods to be aware of the DataTable's `CaseSensitive` property.

Instead, you can use an ExpressionVisitor to change all `StartsWith` (or similar) calls to pass `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for!  So the `ExpressionVisitor` will allow me make expression replacements on-the-fly?  I'll read up on the topic [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `c.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith("sm"` which will make sure you also retrieve lower cased entries. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Younes.  If you read the question, I state that I can't change the original query as they are actually Linq to SQL queries that target a case-insensitive SQL Server database.  I'm hoping to use the DataSets for Unit Testing.